# my ng-submit is not working what is my problem in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

in my code i didn't really understand why my ng-submit is not working..

```
<div ng-controller="cn1" class="col-lg-4" style="border:1px solid brown;border-radius:20px;">
  <h3>Input city:</h3><br>
  <form  class="text-center" ng-submit="access()">
       <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text"class="form-control" ng-model="city">
       </div><br>
       <input type="button" value="Get Details" style="text-align:center;margin-right:500;"  
                     class="btn btn-primary justify-content-center">
   </form>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change type from button to submit :

```
<input type="button" value="Get Details" style="text-align:center;margin-right:500;"  
                     class="btn btn-primary justify-content-center">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Get Details" style="text-align:center;margin-right:500;"  
                     class="btn btn-primary justify-content-center">
```

Comment: Good to hear that it helped . I hope you would not mind giving an upvote or accept it?